# como hacer repetir una frase de solo 16 caracteres

Tags: string, netbeans, bucles, scanner, substring

Quisiera un código para que el usuario ingrese una frase en netbeans por ejemplo:
Programar es lo mejor del mundo!!!
y que el programa repita pero solo dejando pasar 16 caracteres; es decir:

`Programar es lo`
`rogramar es lo m`
`ogramar es lo me`
`.`
`.`
`.` 
`mundo!!!Programa`
`undo!!!Programar`

POR FAVOR AYUDA, INTENTÉ CON FOR Y LENGTH Y SUBSTRING PERO NO TENGO EL RESULTADO DESEADO
GRACIAS

Comment: Puedes agregar lo que has intentado? No escribas con mayúsculas, parece que estuvieras gritando.

Comment: Es decir, quieres que se solo se reitan los primeros 16 caracteres? o que se repita todo despues de los primero 16 caracteres? explica mejor lo que quieres.

Comment: Deberias especificar bien que es lo que quieres hacer

Comment: ¿Por qué hiciste esa edición a tu pregunta?

Comment: Si continuas con esas ediciones te tendré que reportar a los moderadores

Comment: Por favor no generes más trabajo a los otros usuarios vandalizando tu publicación. Publicando en la red [SE] otorgaste derechos no revocables, bajo la [licencia CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0) para que SE pueda distribuir su contenido. Por política de SE, cualquier clase de vandalismo será revertido. Si queres saber más sobre cómo eliminar una publicación, considera mirar: [¿Cómo funciona la eliminación de publicaciones? ¿Por qué podría eliminarse una publicación y qué implica? ¿Cuál es el criterio para eliminar](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1033/22845).

Answer (score 1):

creo que habría que crear una función auxiliar que obtenga la cadena deseada partiendo de una posición. El código sería algo así:

```
public class Main
{
    static String Cadena = "Hola, el mundo de la programación es fantástico !!!";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        int maxCaracteres = Cadena.length();
        int iterations = 0;
        while (iterations < 3)
        {   
            for(int j=0; j < maxCaracteres; j++)
                System.out.println(">> " + GetSubCadena(j) );
            
            iterations++;
        }
}
```

Observa que el bucle while es modificable para que se hagan las iteraciones que se deseen si quieres hacer una especie de marquesina.
La función para calcular la subcadena sería como sigue.

```
static String GetSubCadena(int miPos)
{
     String newCadena="";
     int curPos = miPos;
     // Obtenemos subcadenas sólo de 16 caracteres
     // basándonos en la posición miPos
     for(int i=0; i < 16; i++) 
     {
         if (curPos > Cadena.length()-1) curPos = 0;
       
         newCadena = newCadena + Cadena.substring(curPos, curPos+1);
         
         curPos++;
     }
   
     return newCadena;
}
```

La subcadena la vamos formando caracter a caracter, en función de la posición pasada en el parámetro miPos. Con la variable curPos conseguimos que si sobrepasamos el límite de la cadena comencemos desde el principio.